# How to display in a StackPanel the TextBlock vertically and horizontally?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListView with some elements. For each item I insert an image, the name of the object and one of the properties.

I set the horizontal orientation of the stackpanel.

Displays the image on the left, on the right is the name of the object.

I wanted to then display the property under the name, always to the right of the image. How do I, if the StackPanel I set it horizontally?

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Image Source="Assets/rsz_1rsz_museumiclip.jpg"/>
     <TextBlock Text=""/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NomeMuseo}" FontSize="26"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Paese}"/>//THIS IS
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: can you use a DockPanel in WP8 ?

Comment: DockPanel only W8, not WP8

Comment: Embed them in another stackpanel or just use a grid.

Comment: you can locate both of your properties in another StackPanel with vertical orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DockPanel` isn't an option, I would just use `Grid`. It will let you precisely control that kind of layout:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Height="20"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Image Source="Assets/rsz_1rsz_museumiclip.jpg"/>
     <TextBlock Text=""/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NomeMuseo}" FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Paese}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, you could use two `StackPanels` as ChrisW suggested. Its a little easier to set up, but you lose some control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Image Source="Assets/rsz_1rsz_museumiclip.jpg"/>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NomeMuseo}" FontSize="26"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Paese}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Or `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Image/><StackPanel><TextBlock/><TextBlock/></StackPanel></StackPanel>`